# How to specify a column's default value as a placeholder?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've got a table with multiple columns, several of which are optional. I'm reading records from an external source, in which each record may specify values for the optional columns or not. For each record, I'd like to insert a row into the database with the given values plus the column defaults for any column that's not specified.

If all the columns are specified, I obviously just use a basic INSERT statement:

```
db_cursor.execute("insert into table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) " + 
                  "values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                  (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5))
```

However, if some values are unspecified, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to use the defaults for only those values. You can use the DEFAULT keyword in SQL (or, equivalently, leave those columns out of the insert statement entirely), as e.g.

```
db_cursor.execute("insert into table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) " + 
                  "values (%s, %s, %s, DEFAULT, %s)",
                  (value_1, value_2, value_3, value_5))
```

But you can't pass `'DEFAULT'` as a placeholder value; it'll just become that string.

So far I can only think of three approaches to this problem:

1. Construct the SQL query string itself at run-time based on the input data, rather than using parameterization. This is a very strong anti-pattern due to the usual SQL injection reasons. (This application isn't actually security-critical, but I don't want such anti-patterns in my code.)
2. Write a different query string for each possible combination of specified and unspecified parameters. Here, if four of the columns are optional, that's 2^4 = 16 different commands running the same query. This is obviously unworkable.
3. Make the application aware of the default values and have it send them explicitly in the case where a column is unspecified. This breaks SPOT for the defaults, with all the attending maintenance and interoperability headaches (multiple applications read the database). Of the approaches I can think of, this is probably least bad, but I'd still prefer not to have to do it.

Is there an easier way to manage dynamically sending defaults?

Comment: the main issue is : when you pass less parameters than the query takes, how do you want to match the parameters ?

Comment: If I specify more placeholders in the query than I pass parameters, I assume I get a syntax error. What would be ideal would be some parameter value that causes the corresponding placeholder to become DEFAULT, rather than a literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I usually deal with this is to have a placeholder in place of the column list and string `format()` the list of columns. This is safe, as the list of columns is controlled by the dev, and isn't untrusted user input.

```
stmt_without_col_names = 'INSERT INTO table ({}) VALUES ({})'
input_values = [1, None, 1, None, None]
columns = ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5')
columns_to_keep = {k: v for k, v in zip(columns, input_values) if v is not None}
# note: relies on dict key ordering remaining the same
# this is true if the dict is not modified *at all* between creation
# and the statement execution - use an OrderedDict or other data  
# structure instead if you're worried
format_str = ','.join(['%s'] * len(columns_to_keep))
stmt = stmt_without_col_names.format(columns_to_keep.keys(), format_str)
# stmt looks like "INSERT INTO table (['col3', 'col1']) VALUES (%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(stmt, columns_to_keep.values())
```